# SQL- sort items according to their list order

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have this query:

```
SELECT Name FROM Table WHERE Id IN (414208,479516,4129769,414211,221171,3226290)
```

This returns all the names that have Ids in that list in order they are first found. For example: if Jax with an id 221171 is the first element found, then it will be the first element of that resulting table.

Is there a way so sort the elements by how they appear in that list. I.E. the first name that would be listed in the result should have an Id of 414208, second element should have the id 479516...last element should have the Id 3226290.

Comment: you want to sort by id?

Comment: try `order by Id`.... Hope it helps..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
   Id
FROM 
   Table
WHERE 
   Id IN (414208,479516,4129769,414211,221171,3226290)
ORDER BY 
   FIELD(Id, 414208,479516,4129769,414211,221171,3226290)
```

Comment: You sir, are awesome. Exactly what I wanted.
Is this the only way, or can this be done in a shorter query?

Comment: I'd define those Id's in a variable and use like this: `ORDER BY 
   FIELD(Id, $ids)`

Comment: Thank you. Accepted your answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use mysql function find_in_set

```
SELECT Name FROM Table WHERE Id IN (414208,479516,4129769,414211,221171,3226290) order by FIND_IN_SET(ID,'414208,479516,4129769,414211,221171,3226290')
```